# i need to move my nav-container above layered navigation

Tags: magento, templates, navigation

in magento i need to move nav-container above layered navigation, I can't seem to locate where to change is. I want the category breakdown to be above the filtering options.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Magento's **Template Path Hints** to check the name of template file of every block/section in your frontend. With this knowledge you will be able to edit proper template files. The feature is here:

*System -> Configuration -> Developer -> Debug*
(you need to switch to Website scope in **Current Configuration Scope** field).